# Script in Google sheets to copy selected line to first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive

Trying to find a way to create a script button that when clicked will copy the selected row to the first available empty line below. I have tried but am unable to copy to the first empty row. The closest I have managed is copy to a brand new sheet

Comment: About `I have tried but am unable to copy to the first empty row.`, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you try the [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)() ? this?

so, in the logic of your code, you can simply check what is the last row, and add your content to (row+1).

see also [getMaxRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)() to help you improve your code.